# SharePoint 2013 MySite 404 Error

Tags: 2013, error, my-site, 404

I have configured SharePoint 2013 MySite following http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ee624362.aspx and then tried to troubleshoot my problem using other guides and questions but i still cannot find a solution. When i go to access mysite via the top nav bar it takes me to a random wrong url which produces a 404 file not found error however when i manually enter what should be the correct url it takes me to the correct mysite....

Can anybody help me?

Cheers.

Comment: Can you post example of random URL? Are there any entries in ULS log or windows Event log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about setting up the host, your getting 404 beacuse you dont have access, the mysite is setup and exists, you just need it as a trusted site:

http://www.sharepoint2013.me/Blog/Post/274/Configure-My-Site-trusted-host-locations-in-SharePoint

> **My Site host site collection**
>
> The My Site host site collection is a special site collection that
>   displays the newsfeed and profile pages of all users' My Sites. The
>   site collection's site template must be the My Site host site
>   template, available from the Enterprise tab of the Create Site
>   Collection page. The My Site host site template can be used only once
>   per User Profile service application, which is discussed later in this
>   article.
>
> My Sites require that a site collection exist at the web application
>   root (which is displayed as / in the user interface). Without this,
>   you will receive a message that states that there is no site
>   collection at the root when you try to enable self-service site
>   creation for the web application. Because we recommend that you use a
>   dedicated web application to host My Sites, you should use the root
>   path for the My Site host collection unless you have a specific
>   requirement to create the site collection deeper in the uniform
>   resource locator (URL) path.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here's how I usually set up a new My Sites. Configure whichever way suits you best, of course:

- My Site host: mysites.mycompany.com/
- Default AAM: mysites.mycompany.com/
- Wildcard path: /sites/
- In self-service site creation, path to create new sites: /sites/[%userid%]

In UPS, configure my sites to:

- My Site host: mysites.mycompany.com/
- Personal site location: sites

Trusted My Site hosts:

- mysites.mycompany.com/
- mysites.mycompany.com/sites/

(Of course, use http or https where applicable :) )

Do remember to chunk any previously-configured personal sites you might've created earlier. Otherwise, funkiness might happen. :)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this article describes your problem. 
Give it a try: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2009/01/19/sharepoint-my-site-link-stops-redirecting-users-to-their-personal-site.aspx

They suggest creating MySite collection again.

Answer (score 0):

You might be experiencing similar issues as the ones I had recently. Take a look at [this guide right here](http://www.the15folder.com/incorrect-skydrive-pro-url/). One thing you must be sure of is that you configure your trusted-host locations, new-site creation URLS, root site URLs and My Site Host locations properly, or else you will be getting 404s all over the place.

Is this an upgrade or a new farm?

Comment: It is a brand new farm, thank i will look into this guide.