# SharePoint 2013 - Personal Site Documents "HTTP 404 Not Found"

Tags: sharepoint-server, my-site, 404

Having an issue today with a user that is not able to access their documents in their mySite area and receive a HTTP 404 Not Found error. Confirmed the site collection still exists, is active but only clicking on the documents area displays the error. 
Checked the logs and see the below. 
[image]

Wondering if anyone's experienced something similar. Again it's not a wide-spread issue and only limited to this one at the moment.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out. Noticed the name to the documents library had been renamed. I set the name back to the default "Documents" and starting working as expected again. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is access issue, can you try to add your my site in trusted site, then try again.

Similar thread is discussed here :

[SharePoint 2013 MySite 404 Error](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80030/sharepoint-2013-mysite-404-error)

Comment: It's almost as if the mySite "Documents" library either does not exist anymore or became corrupt somehow and can't be found. I'm a farm admin so I can get to any other user's mySite Documents library from both desktop workstation and server.